# Limited CPU load in external program executed from c++ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shellexecute

My application written in Visual C++ executes an external program with `system` function call.
A system command is a call of [stereoscopic player](http://3dtv.at) instance with certain stereo 3D video file and fullscreen mode passed as parameters.

The problem is that stereoscopic player called from C++ app plays video very slowly. Executing the same command from Windows cmd doesn't cause such behaviour.

When I run built-in Windows CPU load analyzer I get the following results (I can attach a screenshot if needed):

- The stereoscopic player instance executed from cmd loads all available cores simultaneously for 40-50% each (I tried with 2 and 4 cores on different machines).
- The stereoscopic player instance executed from C++ app loads the first core for 90-100% and doesn't load other cores.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try using SetProcessAffinityMask for the process you are spawning.

Comment: hm. A good idea, i'll try for sure

Comment: thank you! I've reached out the solution with SetProcessAffinityMask function!

Comment: Would you mind if I submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SetProcessAffinityMask for the process you are spawning